# Weighted lm model based on number of observations in R

Tags: r, lm, weighted-data

I am computing a linear model in R as such

```
lm(NEP~GPP, data=df)
```

I provide a small subset of the dataframe below:

```
df<- structure(list(Site_ID = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("AR-Slu", 
"AR-Vir", "AU-Tum", "AU-Wac", "BE-Bra", "BE-Jal", "BE-Vie", "BR-Cax", 
"BR-Ma2", "BR-Sa1", "BR-Sa3", "BW-Ma1", "CA-Ca1", "CA-Ca2", "CA-Ca3", 
"CA-Gro", "CA-Man", "CA-NS1", "CA-NS2", "CA-NS3", "CA-NS4", "CA-NS5", 
"CA-NS6", "CA-NS7", "CA-Oas", "CA-Obs", "CA-Ojp", "CA-Qcu", "CA-Qfo", 
"CA-SF1", "CA-SF2", "CA-SF3", "CA-SJ1", "CA-SJ2", "CA-SJ3", "CA-TP1", 
"CA-TP2", "CA-TP3", "CA-TP4", "CA-TPD", "CA-Wp1", "CH-Dav", "CH-Lae", 
"CN-Bed", "CN-Cha", "CN-Din", "CN-Ku1", "CN-Qia", "CZ-Bk1", "De-Bay", 
"DE-Hai", "DE-Har", "DE-Lkb", "DE-Meh", "DE-Obe", "DE-Tha", "DE-Wet", 
"DK-Sor", "ES-Es1", "FI-Hyy", "FI-Sod", "FR-Fon", "FR-Hes", "FR-Lbr", 
"FR-Pue", "GF-Guy", "ID-Pag", "IL-Yat", "IS-Gun", "IT-Col", "IT-Cpz", 
"IT-Lav", "IT-Lma", "IT-Noe", "IT-Non", "IT-Pt1", "IT-Ro1", "IT-Ro2", 
"IT-Sro", "JP-Tak", "JP-Tef", "JP-Tom", "MY-Pso", "NL-Loo", "PA-Spn", 
"PT-Esp", "RU-Fyo", "RU-Skp", "RU-Zot", "SE-Abi", "SE-Fla", "SE-Nor", 
"SE-Sk1", "SE-Sk2", "SE-St1", "UK-Gri", "UK-Ham", "US-Bar", "US-Blo", 
"US-Bn1", "US-Bn2", "Us-Bn3", "US-Dk2", "US-Dk3", "US-Fmf", "US-Fuf", 
"US-Fwf", "US-Gle", "US-Ha1", "US-Ha2", "US-Ho1", "US-Ho2", "US-Ho3", 
"US-KS1", "US-Lph", "US-Me1", "US-Me2", "US-Me3", "US-Me4", "US-Me5", 
"US-Me6", "US-MMS", "US-Moz", "US-NC1", "US-NC2", "US-NR1", "US-Oho", 
"US-Pfa", "US-Prr", "US-Skr", "US-SO2", "US-SO3", "US-Sp1", "US-Sp2", 
"US-Sp3", "US-Syv", "US-Umb", "US-Umd", "US-Wbw", "US-Wcr", "US-Wi0", 
"US-Wi1", "US-Wi2", "US-Wi3", "US-Wi4", "US-Wi5", "US-Wi6", "US-Wi7", 
"US-Wi8", "US-Wi9", "VU-Coc", "CA-Cbo", "CN-Lao", "ID-Buk", "JP-Fuj", 
"RU-Ab", "RU-Be", "RU-Mix"), class = "factor"), NEP = c(1262.24986565392, 
304.238143564202, -197.94530456129, 569.328627431765, -80.9759707693011, 
-147.441009093309), GPP = c(2437.9937774539, 2172.34112930298, 
1671.89236265421, 2479.44521586597, 1518.57838335112, 1310.79992516536
)), .Names = c("Site_ID", "NEP", "GPP"), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, there are different sites (Site_ID) which have different number of observations. I am wondering whether I should include a weight in my linear model based on the number of observations per site or not. I assume that sites with more observations will have more weight or not?. If so, what would be the best way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a model where 1 site = 1 observation, then you can use the weighting parameter of ['lm'](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lm.html):

```
lm(formula, data, subset, weights, na.action,
   method = "qr", model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE,
   singular.ok = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, offset, ...)
```

Otherwise, you could also model based on 1 line in your current data-frame = 1 observation. In this case, you don't need weights.

I would need to know more about your application scenario to decide which approach is better.

Comment: What I want to avoid is that the sites with more observations have higher weight than the sites only 1 observation, for instance.

Comment: That is dealt with in both approaches that I mentioned. For the moment, you have sometimes multiple lines for 1 site in your data-set. You say you want to make them into 1 line and give this line more weight. This is possible with the weight parameter of 'lm'. It is however not clear why you would need to assemble lines like this.